# Delphi XE5 firemonkey api call

Tags: android, delphi, audio, firemonkey

I am trying to record audio in firemonkey by calling android api TJAudioRecord directly but it doesn't work, audioRecord.getState returns STATE_UNINITIALIZED whatever I tried, please help?

There is some error in this function

```
  audioRecord := 

    TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.init(TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                                                 16000,
                                                 TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                                  TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                                  bufferSize);
```

full code

```
 bufferSize := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.getMinBufferSize(16000,
                                                            TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                                           TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

     if (bufferSize <> TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) then
     begin
      audioRecord := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.init(TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.VOICE_COMMUNICATION,
                                                 16000,
                                                 TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                                  TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                                  bufferSize);
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(buffersize));
       if (audioRecord.getState = TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.STATE_INITIALIZED)then begin
      //then begin
      audioRecord.startRecording;
      ShowMessage('ok');
      end;
    end;
     except
    ShowMessage('Error 0');
    end;
```

Comment: You are checking the result of `getMinBufferSize()` for `ERROR_BAD_VALUE` (-2), but you are not checking it for `ERROR` (-1) as well, which would indicate a hardware problem. I would suggest you check the result for `>0` instead of specific errors.

Comment: buffersize is ok, it returns 4096, it won't initialize, also I have turned on audiorecord in persmission list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code and it works on my Samsung Galaxy Note III.

```
  Ses := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.init(TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.MIC, 11025, TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 44100 * 2);
  (Ses As JAudioRecord).startRecording;
  Okunan := 0;
  M := TMemoryStream.Create;
  for I := 1 to 2 do
  Begin
    Tampon := TJavaArray<SmallInt>.Create(44100);
    Okunan := Okunan + (Ses As JAudioRecord).read(Tampon, 0, 44100);
    M.Write(Tampon.Data^, Tampon.Length * 2);
    Tampon.Free;
  End;
  (Ses As JAudioRecord).stop;
  Ses.release;
  M.SaveToFile(TPath.GetRingtonesPath+'/ses.raw');
```

Comment: thanks, I have modified my code with your example and it is working

Comment: I'm glad that you have solved it. Would you accept the answer then?

Comment: sure :) I need to figure out to put this code in the thread and that is it, standard deplhi TThread throws exception

Comment: I tried it with a thread object and I also get the exception.

Comment: Invalid argument (22)

Comment: hm I am working in Android Studio now, Delphi is just not good enough for android, also file size is an issue same app written in delphi for android have 30mb but in original Android ide only 500kb

Comment: Delphi lets you write code that runs on multiple platforms (iOS, Android, OSX, Win32, and Win64). The cross-platform support adds overhead. If you don't need cross-platform, Delphi isn't the right choice. If you do, it beats Android Studio hands down for everything not Android when you try to use the same source. :-)